# I am working on an optimization problem and I'm stuck on calculating a distance using matrix

Tags: mathematical-optimization

This project is about writing a lineair program that puts people who are in the same groups side by side on a plane and I'm stuck on the program 
we have a matrix with 6 columns and 29 raws. each (i,j,k) represents (client,col,raw) and every client belongs to a certain group K 
but as it is a three dimentional problem I didn't know how to formulate it

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow, please take the tour before asking another question: https://stackoverflow.com/tour I've downvoted it as I see several issues with it, it's too broad as you haven't written what you've attemted so far, it's unclear what you're asking as it seems like you haven't even included the entire question and it's off-topic as well as linear programming questions are solved on https://math.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 0):

If we have the binary variable:

```
x(p,r,s) = 1 if passenger p is sitting in row r, seat s
           0 otherwise
```

then we can maximize:

```
max sum  x(p1,r,s)*x(p2,r,s+1)
```

where the summation is over all (p1,p2) in the same group, and over all rows and seats. This is non-convex, but you can linearize the product (this a product of binary variables). This leads to:

```
max sum y(p1,p2,r,s)
y(p1,p2,r,s) <= x(p1,r,s)
y(p1,p2,r,s) <= x(p2,r,s+1)
0 <= y(p1,p2,r,s) <= 1
```

Probably "row" needs to be defined as seats next to each other, i.e. with a single aisle:

```
 (r1,s1)(r1,s2)(r1,s3)     (r2,s1)(r2,s2)(r2,s3)
 (r3,s1)(r3,s2)(r3,s3)     (r4,s1)(r4,s2)(r4,s3)
```

Of course you need to add standard "assignment" constraints (each seat is occupied only once, each passenger is seated).

Comment: Thank you for your help but I didn't quiet understand what you did here :
max sum y(p1,p2,r,s)

y(p1,p2,r,s) <= x(p1,r,s)

y(p1,p2,r,s) <= x(p2,r,s+1)
0 <= y(p1,p2,r,s) <= 1
how is y(i,i+1,r,s) is maximized twice ?

Comment: I don't think it is.